# backbone case insensitive search

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, case-insensitive

I have a code similar to this one http://jsfiddle.net/kianoshp/YWSSp/77/

I think there must be changes on part

```
$('#filter').on('keyup', function(e) {
        filteredCollection = new FilteredCollection();
        filteredCollection.reset(filterTable(administratorCollection,
    $(e.currentTarget).val()));
        resetTable(filteredCollection);
});
```

And I can't think of answer how to make search case insensitive.

Comment: in javascript you can just do var isEqual = str1.toUpperCase() === str2.toUpperCase();

Comment: in addition you can add `$.trim()` so trailing spaces won't hit your results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a search case-insensitive, you upper- or lowercase both search term and search value.

In your code:

```
filterTable = function(collection, filterValue) {
    if (filterValue === "") {
        return collection.toJSON();
    }
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
//                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return collection.filter(function(data) {
        return _.some(_.values(data.toJSON()), function(value) {
            value = (!isNaN(value) ? value.toString() : value.toLowerCase());
//                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            return value.indexOf(filterValue) >= 0;
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks! But this is only working if all the letters are lowercase or uppercase. If they are different it won't really work.

Comment: That's because you normalize them to be all the same (lower)case?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cqPdD/3/ try to search for example Fricis writing in searchbox "FRICIS", it won't find Fricis.

Comment: i added after value.toLowerCase().indexOf and everything worked as I wanted. Thank you!! :))

Comment: Ah, I see now. Got confused by that is-not-no-number check and added `toLowerCase` in the wrong place. Updated answer